# Shared native library in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have project that optionally uses a native library. Since the size of the native library is quite large. I would create two separate packages (the app1 which is master app and app2 is a secondary app in which contains only the native library) and make them available in Market. If users downloads app2 from Market, they have additional feature.

Question: how can I load the native library packed in app2 from app1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for your reply. My workaround is download the native library and copy it into app's data folder on demand (when users need "app2") since loading a native library from data partition has worked well.

Comment: Would you please describe your solution in more detail, I have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881411/load-native-shared-library-from-another-android-application
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can call System.load with the library path. So sharing between apps should not be a problem as long as it is in a directory accessible by both apps. I believe OpenCV uses this approach.