# Load native shared library from another Android application

Tags: android, android-ndk

I need to distribute an application (a player), which depends on a native library built for a given ARM version and extension (Tegra, Neon). This native library is quite large so I can’t distribute all its versions in one universal package. So I decided to split the application into one small universal .apk and more specialized .apks – plug-ins without any activities.

How can I access a specialized native shared library in the plug-in app from the main host application? Is it possible to use simply

```
System.loadLibrary("path_to_library");
```

If so, how can I get the path to that library?

How to solve this problem in case it is not possible?

Comment: I am not completely sure you can load libraries which are not included in your apk. Have you tried uploading a `.so` to a rooted device and tried to `System.loadLibrary` with its path?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, i have just tried it and it works.

Comment: Ok. How are you going to set the path?

Comment: Since I know the package name of the plug-in application, I use `String path = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("packagename",0).applicationInfo.dataDir + "/lib/libname.so";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.loadLibrary()` takes a library name and maps it to a full path somehow.

foo => libfoo.so

The system normally checks the apk itself and then usually `/system/lib/`

If you have a full path, use `System.load()`

In any case it will be a hassle to manage the location of your lib unless it's either in the apk or with all the system libs.

I'd just pack the specific lib with the apk.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot! I didn’t know about the System.load method, now it works as expected. I can’t pack all libs into one universal .apk, they are huge, it would take 50 MB on disc and more than 100 MB installed…

Comment: _"The system normally checks the apk itself and then usually /system/lib/"_ do you know if the order is guaranteed to be this? I would like to know what happens if both an apk and /system/lib contain the same library, is it 100% sure that the .so to be loaded will be the one in the apk?

Comment: It looks at the apk first, then the normal system libraries. I have apps that pack libs that are different (newer/modified/hacked) than the same named system libs.

Answer (score 1):

Eight years later, the major concerns of the TS have been addressed: there are splits that can produce smaller APK for each ABI, there are app bundles that allow easier packaging, there are extensions that even allow to delay download of a native library until it is really needed by the app…

Still, the same technique to `System.load("/data/data/{app-package}/lib/lib{library-name}.so")` still works, and may be useful in some scenarios.