# Loading remote libraries from different package

Tags: android, android-studio, package, communication, mobile-development

I had a situation where I am going to develop two android applications and lets say the first application App A will be having the different libraries in it and the second application lets say App B that I develop should be able to load the libraries from the App A. User should not move between applications using Intents, user should be in the App B and he should never know that the libraries are from App A. We need to develop the applications such that user should feel that he is loading the libraries from the same application itself but in reality those applications will be in the other application.

I think that we can achieve this by Package Visibility but not in greater detail. It would be really helpful if someone help me step by step process.

I had thought of Content Providers, IPC Mechanisms like Messenger and AIDL but instead of that complex architecture I found that we can implement this by using the package visibility concept. Firstly we need to register the package of App A in App B and then load the libraries from App A in the App B. If someone knows how I can do this step by step, it would be really helpful for me.

Comment: Thank you for your response @CommonsWare . But can't we able to load the libraries of App A in the App B by getting the Application info from package manager like below PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager(); ApplicationInfo appInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA); I need to just load the libraries that are present in the App A into the App B so that I can use them in the App B seamlessly. I can't have all my libraries in single application because of the performance issues of the application

Answer (score 2):

> the first application App A will be having the different libraries in it and the second application lets say App B that I develop should be able to load the libraries from the App A

If you are expecting that App B will use *libraries* packaged inside of App A, that is not an option in Android. If you want App B to communicate with App A, you will need to use various forms of inter-process communication (IPC), such as:

- App B starting an activity from App A
- App B starting a service from App A
- App B binding a service from App A
- App B sending a broadcast to App A
- App B interacting with a `ContentProvider` supplied by App A

> I had thought of Content Providers, IPC Mechanisms like Messenger and AIDL

Yes, those are all viable options.

> but instead of that complex architecture

If you do not like IPC, do not have two apps. In addition to the complexity for *you*, there is complexity for the *user*. App B will not work — either entirely or in part — if App A is unavailable for any reason, such as:

- It has not been installed
- It has been installed but the current user cannot run it, such as via a restricted profile

(there might also be a scenario involving work profiles, but I don't have enough experience with those to say for certain)

It will be much simpler for everybody if you have a single app, rather than two apps.

> I found that we can implement this by using the package visibility concept

No. All the package visibility rules do is determine *if* App B can talk to App A, or even know that App A exists. You still need to use IPC to actually talk.

> Firstly we need to register the package of App A in App B and then load the libraries from App A in the App B.

That is not how package visibility works. You might consider reading [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) on package visibility. FWIW, I also cover package visibility in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/R/pages/chap-package-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/R).

Comment: Good answer, clear information.

Comment: Thank you for your response @CommonsWare . But can't we able to load the libraries of App A in the App B by getting the Application info from package manager like below 

PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

`ApplicationInfo appInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);`

**I need to just load the libraries that are present in the App A into the App B so that I can use them in the App B seamlessly. I can't have all my libraries in single application because of the performance issues of the application**

Comment: @MuthyamSriram: `getApplicationInfo()` does not allow you to "load the libraries", for any definition of "load the libraries" that I know of. "I can't have all my libraries in single application because of the performance issues of the application" -- that statement does not make much sense to me.

Comment: @CommonsWare : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881411/load-native-shared-library-from-another-android-application please refer to this question. I had the same situation.

Comment: @vitakot : Could you please check my question and give me some more info about how to add .so file in android studio project as per your answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881411/load-native-shared-library-from-another-android-application

Comment: @MuthyamSriram: Now we are making some progress. Your question refers to "libraries", whereas your last two comments are about native shared libraries (`.so` files). "Libraries" in Android app development tend to refer to Java/Kotlin libraries, not native shared libraries. In terms of native shared libraries, as is noted in the question that you linked to, [there are other techniques for reducing app size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61695564/115145). Also, I suspect that security changes in recent years will preclude your approach.